# How should I access this method statically?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model, Person, which has the following function

```
public function findRecordByIdm($idm)
{
   $record =  Person::find($idm);
   return $record;
}
```

In a separate controller altogether, ProspectController, I want to call to that function to get the Person record returned by the $idm. If I do it without declaring it a static method, I get a

```
non static method should not be called statically
```

I know that due to their difficulty in testing, I should not simply declare the method as static. How, instead, should I go about making this function accessible from the ProspectController?

Comment: `(new Person())->findRecordByIdm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find is not a method on Model, it's actually an instance method on the Builder class.  Because of the definition of `Model::__callStatic`, `Model::find` (or any other non-existent method) is passed towards a new instance of the Builder class.  This is the only reason why you can call find both statically and non-statically, because `Model::find` doesn't actually exist.

You can either use an instance of the model, like u_mulder suggests, but this is one case where I'd argue a static method is fine.  This follows a similar design to the factory pattern where the whole point of this static method is to prepare and return an instance of the model.

Answer (score -1):

This question will definitely trigger varying opinions as we all favor one pattern over another but going the Laravel way, you should be doing this in your controller and not your model.
In ProspectController.php

```
public function findRecordByIdm($idm)
{
   $record =  Person::find($idm);
   return $record;
}
```

If you intend to reuse the function in different places, you should consider using Services and Repositories...

Comment: Why in the controller over the model?  A model, or a repository, would definitely seem like the right place for this.

Comment: @Devon...  Different people will definitely have varying opinion about this...but if we are to go the Laravel way, this is definitely a `controller` method...